# Unmarshaling JSON into Struct

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying to Unmarshal the following JSON string into the struct below;

```
{
   "io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault":{
      "lastModifiedAt":{
         "string":"2022-09-01T02:22:19+00:00"
      },
      "taxRateId":{
         "int":5
      },
      "basedOn":{
         "string":"Markup"
      },
      "priceTax":{
         "double":2.04
      },
      "price":{
         "int":24
      },
      "status":{
         "string":"active"
      },
      "costPrice":{
         "int":24
      },
      "createdAt":{
         "string":"2022-09-01T02:22:19+00:00"
      },
      "productId":{
         "int":3545
      },
      "ownershipId":{
         "int":1
      },
      "dbId":{
         "int":3655
      },
      "markupPercentage":{
         "int":0
      }
   }
}
```

```
type Wrapper struct {
    Message `json:"io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault"`
}

type Message struct {
    DbId Field `json:"dbId"`
}

type Field struct {
    Value map[string]interface{}
}
```

But it gives me an empty value for the `Field` map. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have extra level of nesting:

```golang
type Message struct {
    DbId map[string]interface{} `json:"dbId"`
}
```

`dbId` property's value is a `map` of `string`s to anything.

Comment: [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mLAUj3zbx8K) demonstrating this.

Comment: @Brits thanks, or even https://go.dev/play/p/rZ9DkW_qg5F (changed the output format)